# tail --follow multiple files and preserve atomic lines

Tags: linux

I want to follow multiple log files and output the incoming lines to a single pipe.  However, doing so without much thought (e.g. `tail -F`) can produce broken lines:  For instance, lines `ABC\n` and `XYZ\n` from two logs can get mixed up and become `ABXYZ\nC\n`.

Here's an example:

```
$ >a >b
$ (echo -n a >>a; sleep 2; echo A >>a) &
$ (echo -n b >>b; sleep 2; echo B >>b) &
$ tail -Fq a b
```

Ideally, this produces `aA\n` and `bB\n`.  In reality, something like `abA\nB\n` is produced.

**How do I output these lines without them getting mixed up?**

Here are some things I've tried

- Instead of using a single `tail -Fq`, I tried separate `tail` instances for each file:

  ```
  $ (trap 'kill 0' EXIT; tail -F a & tail -F b & wait)
  ```

  However, I think this just moves the problem from `tail` to the pipe buffer and the problem isn't resolved.
- Use separate instances and use `grep` to buffer each line.

  ```
  $ (trap 'kill 0' EXIT; tail -F a | grep -F '' & tail -F b | grep -F '' & wait)
  ```

  This appears to work.  However, I'm not sure how durable this is.  I think it has the same restrictions discussed in this question: [Is echo atomic when writing single lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9926616/is-echo-atomic-when-writing-single-lines)

  (Also, is there a better way of doing what `grep -F ''` does here?)

Comment: You may need something more than the command line. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7749302/writing-a-python-daemon-to-manage-multiple-remote-tails

Comment: Use [multitail](http://www.vanheusden.com/multitail/) or [wtail](http://www.teaser.fr/~amajorel/wtail/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that works without installing extra programs such as [*multitail*](https://www.vanheusden.com/multitail/).

It's very similar to the question's second example but the command to use is `grep -F '' --line-buffered`.  `grep -F` here can be replaced with `fgrep` for short.  Regarding `grep -F` / `fgrep` versus normal regex grep, using fixed string grep is *slightly* faster than something like `grep ^ --line-buffered` for the same purpose.

Putting it together, a multi-line version is:

```bsh
(
trap 'kill 0' EXIT
tail -F a | fgrep '' --line-buffered &
tail -F b | fgrep '' --line-buffered &
wait
)
```

The subshell `(` `)` may not be required  if this is going into a shell script.  To turn it into a one-liner, get rid of the line breaks and put semicolons (`;`) at the end of lines that don't end with an ampersand (`&`).

#### The solution in depth

There's actually two problems that this handles:

First, `tail -F` will consume and output the bytes in the files as it sees them, without waiting for the end of line.  This is just the way it is and `tail` currently provides no way to changes this.  Therefore, we cannot do `tail -Fq a b` and must instead use separate processes for each file.

Second, after doing `tail -F` on each file, the problem remains that the output can get mixed up in the pipe buffer.  Since `tail` flushes at arbitrary bytes and not on whole lines, there's ample cause for this.  Specifying `stdbuf -oL` to line buffer `tail` does not change this as tail seems to overwrite this.

To work around the second problem, we need to use something like `grep` to wait on whole lines before outputting.  Furthermore, we need to specify `--line-buffered` otherwise grep itself will buffer its output and flush when the buffer is full, which may not be at a line boundary.

#### Miscellaneous

To explain what `trap 'kill 0' EXIT` ... `wait` does, it's required to prevent `tail -F` processes from being left behind when something like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> is used to break out.